# Confidence intervals for population

Tags: confidence-interval, central-limit-theorem

These might be slightly basic questions for confidence intervals but I can't think exactly how to resolve them.

Considering an example where I have access to the entire population e.g. the annual revenue for a company over the last decade $R_i, i\in{1,..10}$ where revenue is generated from sales.

1) Is it a valid approach to estimate confidence intervals for e.g. each year's revenue by considering the distribution of revenue by week for each year? For example, weekly revenue is $r_{ij}, j\in1...52$, with mean $\mu_i$ and standard deviation $\sigma_i$ then use the CLT to generate a CI for the revenue sum, i.e. using $R_i\sim N\big(n\mu_i, \sqrt{n}\sigma_i\big)$ to get $n\mu_i\pm1.96\sqrt{n}\sigma_i$ for the 95% CI. What is the difference between this weekly approach and an approach based on considering the distribution of revenue across sales?

2) In such a case where data for the entire population is available, what is the interpretation of the confidence interval? i.e. what is the true parameter that the CI seeks to enclose in this case?

Comment: Maybe you can consider your data a "random" sample from a population that includes the future. Then it somewhat makes sense to calculate confidence intervals (although making strong assumptions).